What is the role of m and Sn in the below question?
In a network using Go-Back-N protocol with m = 3 and the sending window of size 7, the values of variables are Sf= 62, Sn=66, Rn=64. Assume that the network does not duplicate or reorder the packets.In a network using Go-Back-N protocol with m = 3 and the sending window of size 7, the values of variables are Sf= 62, Sn=66, Rn=64. Assume that the network does not duplicate or reorder the packets

What are the sequence numbers of data packets in transit ?

What are the acknowledgement numbers of ACK packets in transit ?
Sf = First packet for which ack not received.
Sn = sequence number that will be assigned to the next packet to be sent.
Rn = sequence number of next packet expected in receive window.


As per my understanding, the  answer to 1) should be 64 and 65. As the window will have sequence numbers from 62 to 68 . 66 is the next sequence number to be used which means packets with sequence numbers from 62 to 65 already sent. Since Rn = 64 , it implies receiver has received packets 62 and 63 and now expecting packet with seq number 64. So 64 and 65 are data pakcets in transit
2) Since Rn = 64, so that means Ack in transit will have sequence numbers 63 and 64.
Is my understanding correct ? In that case, the value of m plays no role here. Similarly, Sn also plays no role here.
Thanks in advance.
